# Android - How to make buttons listen more than one time

Tags: java, android, button, listeners

I have an app with a home screen and a bunch of `buttons` on it, and therefore `listeners` for each. After the user clicks on one of the `buttons`, a new `layout` is brought up and that `layout` has a `back button` with a `listener`.

The problem is that whenever the user presses the `back button`, the home screen `layout` is brought back up but none of the `listeners` work for the `buttons` anymore.

Here is some sample code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main); // return to home screen

    // sets up a listener for when the GCF main screen button is clicked.
    GCFButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            setContentView(R.layout.gcf); // change to the gcf layout
            Button back = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnBack); // set up the back button in the gcf layout
            back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() // put a listener on back button
            {
                public void onClick(View v) 
                {
                    setContentView(R.layout.main); // return to home screen
                }
            });

            Button GCFCalculate = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnCalculate); // set up the gcf button in the gcf layout
            GCFCalculate.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener() // put listener on gcf button in gcf layout
            {
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    // do stuff
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure that there is a `method` built into Android that allows you to do this, but my first thought is `recursion`.

The problem is that your listeners are in the `onCreate` method, which means that after they are run through, they won't repeat. In the `back button listener`,
when you set the `content view` to be the home screen again, that won't set up the `listeners` again, that will just *change* the `content view`.

To fix that, you would have to call the `onCreate` method again, once the `back button` is clicked, because then it would run your whole code with all the `listeners`
from the home screen again.

I suggest putting all of the `listeners` in a `listeners()` method, and then calling that method `recursively` when needed. It would need to be called in `onCreate(...)`,
as well as when the `back button` is clicked:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    listeners(); // set up all the listeners for the buttons    
}

public void listeners()
{
    setContentView(R.layout.main); // return to home screen
    // sets up a listener for when the GCF main screen button is clicked.
    GCFButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            setContentView(R.layout.gcf); // change to the gcf layout
            Button back = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnBack); // set up the back button in the gcf layout
            back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() // put a listener on back button
            {
                public void onClick(View v) 
                {
                    listeners(); // recursively call the listeners again to 'start over'
                }
            });

            Button GCFCalculate = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnCalculate); // set up the gcf button in the gcf layout
            GCFCalculate.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener() // put listener on gcf button in gcf layout
            {
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    // do stuff
            }
        });
    }
});
```

}

I would also recommend putting the `back button listener` in its own `method`, so that it can be called every time the `layout` is changed.

Answer (score 2):

You should not change a screen with `setContentView()`. Screens are changed in Android by starting a new Activity with `startActivity(new Intent(...))` or with Fragments like recommended by Malimo (which is a bit more difficult to do but much nicer). You call two times `setContentView()` where one is destroying the other one.

Answer (score 1):

in my opinion you should use fragments for your contentviews. so every fragment will be responsible for its contentview and can add listeners each time it is displayed... 
http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html